# Node.js Best practice to wait for same function to finish twice

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, callback, promise

My POST requests calls the same function twice and sends the data that I'm receiving from that function back to the client.

**But I'm struggling on how to wait for both function calls to finish.**

I tried using Promises but somehow it didn't work for me.

```
let socket_latest_data = new net.Socket();
let socket_optionmenu_data = new net.Socket();

app.post("/query_latest_data", function (req, res) {
  let gauge_data = null;
  let option_data = null;
  let combined_data = {};
  gauge_data = query_data(socket_latest_data, "d");
  option_data = query_data(socket_optionmenu_data, "r");
  Object.assign(combined_data, JSON.parse(gauge_data), JSON.parse(option_data));
  res.end(combined_data);
});

function query_data(socket, char) {
  socket.connect(2711, '192.168.1.173', function () {
    socket.write(char);
  });
  socket.on('data', function (data) {
    socket.removeAllListeners();
    data = data.toString().replace(/[\[\]&]+|nan/g, '0').replace(/\s/g, '');
    return data;
  });
}
```

** **UPDATE** **

The solution is to use `Promise.all()` Method. Its important to use `.then(function()` part because otherwise i will just receive `[undefined, undefined]`

**Code**

```
app.post("/query_latest_data", function (req, res) {
  let combined_data = {};
  Promise.all([query_data(socket_latest_data, "d"), query_data(socket_optionmenu_data, "r")]).then(function(data) {
    Object.assign(combined_data, JSON.parse(data[0]), JSON.parse(data[1]));
    console.log(combined_data);
    res.end(JSON.stringify(combined_data));
  });
});

function query_data(socket, char) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    socket.connect(2711, '192.168.1.173', function () {
      socket.write(char);
    });
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
      socket.removeAllListeners();
      data = data.toString().replace(/[\[\]&]+|nan/g, '0').replace(/\s/g, '');
      res(data);
    });
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Make this a promise:

```
function query_data(socket, char) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        socket.connect(2711, '192.168.1.173', function () {
            socket.write(char);
        });
        socket.on('data', function (data) {
            socket.removeAllListeners();
            data = data.toString().replace(/[\[\]&]+|nan/g, '0').replace(/\s/g, '');
            res(data);
        });
    })

}

app.post("/query_latest_data", async (req, res) {
    let combined_data = {};
    let combined_data_arr = await Promise.all([query_data(socket_latest_data, "d"), query_data(socket_optionmenu_data, "r")])
    Object.assign(combined_data, JSON.parse(combined_data_arr[0]), JSON.parse(combined_data_arr[1]));
    res.end(combined_data);
});
```

**Note:** The code is not tested, given as a hint from top of my head.

Comment: this doesn't work unfortunately, you need to add a "then" to Promise.all otherwise i'm receiving [undefined, undefined]. But it works now using: 

 `Promise.all([query_data(socket_latest_data, "d"), query_data(socket_optionmenu_data, "r")]).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data[0]);
  });`

Comment: yeah lol. Sorry. Changing the answer :) Wanted to use async/await

Comment: i updated the question. maybe you could copy it to your answer, so people will see this as solution.

Comment: You can check using async/await. It is visually clearer

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use callback in query_data function like below. If you want to use promise use async and await. Hope this works

```
app.post("/query_latest_data", function (req, res) {
 let combined_data = {};
 query_data(socket_latest_data, "d",(gauge_data)=>{
    query_data(socket_optionmenu_data, "r",(option_data)=>{
      Object.assign(combined_data, JSON.parse(gauge_data), JSON.parse(option_data));
      res.end(combined_data);
    });
  });  
});
function query_data(socket, char,callBack) {
 socket.connect(2711, '192.168.1.173', function () {
 socket.write(char);  
});
 socket.on('data', function (data) {
  socket.removeAllListeners();
  data = data.toString().replace(/[\[\]&]+|nan/g, '0').replace(/\s/g, '');
  callBack(data);
 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I already got the solution myself using promises. i forgot to use `.then()`